# Showing/Adding <tr>'s dynamically

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this code:

```
<table id="SomeTable">
<tr>
    <td>Rows:</td>
    <td><select name="Rows" id="Rows">
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                    </select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>#1</td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
</tr>
......
<tr>
    <td>#5</td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
</tr></table>
```

Is it possible to somehow dynamically show the number of rows selected in the droplist? And add the current number in the first  or each row using JQuery?

Which way is the best to solve this? And is it possible to animate those tr's as they are removed/added?

/M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`:gt()`](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) selector, like this:

```
$("#Rows").change(function() {
  $("#SomeTable tr").show().filter(":gt(" + $(this).val() + ")").hide();
});
```

It's a 0-based index, but since you have an extra row up top with the drop down itself, this works out perfect.  Another slightly cleaner alternative is [`.slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/), like this:

```
$("#Rows").change(function() {
  $("#SomeTable tr").show().slice(parseInt($(this).val(), 10)).hide();
});
```

For the animating, you *could* do some fading, but animating table rows in particular is nasty in IE, I'd stay away from it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#Rows').change(function() { 
    alert($(this).val()); 
});
```

I'm not sure what you mean, are you trying to add n numbers of element based on the select box's value?